# Looking for an easy way to find colors for css

Tags: css, colors

I'm looking for an easy way to view colors / choose colors for my CSS styles besides just the generic ones like:

```
color: Purple;
```

I just want an easy way to view / select them based on their #XXXXXX (Hex Color?)

Thanks!

Comment: Converting an older, low-quality answer to a comment: here’s a nice link: http://html-color-codes.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Colorpicker.com](http://www.colorpicker.com/)

I find myself using this all of the time for design-related issues, as it also features analogous colors, complementary colors, and other color-scheming tools.

If you want a desktop type solution, I know that [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) features a similar desktop-based solution. Hope this helps

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for - I probably should have just done a search before posting this. Sorry.

Comment: there is good site [here](http://www.color-hex.com/color/808080) , just select the color and see the color in `div` etc and [another](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html#fg=33FF33,bg=333333) to check hue, saturation , finally [this](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-font-color-for-text-on-a-white-background-screen) article to keep in mind that your color doesn't give stress to eyes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox and Firebug, [Firepicker](http://thedarkone.github.com/firepicker/) could be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://html-color-codes.com/

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop, take a screenshot and select the [eyedropper tool](http://see.weareinto.com/3qvP) click a color on the document color area, then click the swatch in the toolbar to bring up the [Color Picker](http://see.weareinto.com/3qyz). The hex color is there :P

Answer (score 0):

Piknik color picker http://color.aurlien.net/ is very sleek/cool and might be just what you're looking for. Also, if you want to extract a color from a particular webpage, and use firefox, you can install the ColorZilla Firefox add-on. Personally, I use the eye-drop color pickers in ColorZilla in combination with Adobe Photoshop to get hex colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try ColorSnapper

Has options for Hex, RGBA and even XCode!
http://colorsnapper.com/

Answer (score 0):

With hundreds of thousands or maybe more custom made colors and pallets to choose from as well as the ability to make your own hex's [colourlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/) is by far the best I've encountered.